# Beautifulsoup: findAll recursive doesn't work

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get articles from wired.com.
Generally their articles' content look like this:

```
<article itemprop="articleBody">
   <p>Some text</p>
   <p>Next text</p>
   <p>...</p>
   <p>...</p>
</article>
```

or like this:

```
<article itemprop="articleBody">
    <div class="listicle-captions marg-t...">
        <p></p>

    </div>

 </article>
```

So I want if the page is of type 1, the `<p>` and `<h>` are extracted, while if the page is of type 2 - do something else. So, if the `<p>` and `<h>` are direct descendants of `<article>`, then it's type 1.
  I tried the following code, it looks for `<p>` and `<h>` and prints out the tag names. The thing is, the `recursive="False"` doesn't seem to help because when tested on type 2 page, it finds the tags, while it shouldn't (I espected to get a `NonType` object).

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import datetime
import html
import sys

articleUrl="https://www.wired.com/2016/07/greatest-feats-inventions-100-years-boeing/"

soupArticle=BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen(articleUrl), "html.parser")

articleBody=soupArticle.find("article", {"itemprop":"articleBody"})
articleContentTags=articleBody.findAll(["h1", "h2","h3", "p"], recursive="False")

for tag in articleContentTags:
    print(tag.name)
    print(tag.parent.encode("utf-8"))
```

Why doesn't it work?

PS Also, is there a difference between using `findAll` and `findChildren` in general and in this particular case? These two look the same to me..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The string literal `"False"` is not the same as use the *boolean* `False`, you need to actually pass `recursive=False`:

```
articleBody.find_all(["h1", "h2","h3", "p"], recursive=False)
```

Any non empty string is going to be considered a truthy value , the only string you could pass that would work would be an empty string i.e `recursive=""`.

```
In [17]: bool("False")
Out[17]: True

In [18]: bool("foo")
Out[18]: True

In [19]: bool("")
Out[19]: False
```

But stick to using the actual *boolean* `False`, also you will get an empty *list/ResultSet* returned with `recursive=False`, not None as you are calling *find_all* not *find*.